# (Un)Set nested array values by string input

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, session, reference

I have a function like this:

```
Session.get = function(key) {
    if (!window["_SESSION"] || typeof key == 'undefined') {
        return window["_SESSION"] || {};
    }

    if (key.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        return window["_SESSION"][key] || {};
    }

    var keyArr = key.split('.'), val = window["_SESSION"];

    for ( var i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof val[keyArr[i]] === 'undefined') {
            return null;
        }
        val = val[keyArr[i]];
    }

    return val;
}
```

This function allows me to get nested values without temporary variable outside of the function. Example `Session.get('var.nestedvar')` is returns value of `window[_SESSION']['var']['nestedvar']`.

Bat how can I (un)set variables like so?  Tried to `delete val;` but didn't work.. How do the javascript references work?  Does anybody know any alternative to accomplish similiar functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete by parent like this:

```
[10:00:00.380] a = {'root': {'home':'~'}}
[10:00:00.385] ({root:{home:"~"}})
--
[10:00:09.625] b = a['root']
[10:00:09.631] ({home:"~"})
--
[10:00:20.569] delete b['home']
[10:00:20.573] true
[10:00:21.684] a
[10:00:21.688] ({root:{}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a slight modification of your existing code, like this:

```
Session.delete = function(key) {
    if (!window["_SESSION"] || typeof key == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    if (key.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        if (key) {
            delete key;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var keyArr = key.split('.'), val = window["_SESSION"];

    var keyDepth = keyArr.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < keyDepth-1; i++) {
        if (typeof val[keyDepth] === 'undefined') {
            return null;
        }
        val = val[keyDepth];
    }
    if (val[keyDepth-1]) {
        delete val[keyDepth-1];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could set `keyArr.length-1` in a variable, because now you're calculateing it in every iteration of the cycle + two more times.

Comment: Just as i needed, but core1024 was first, so +1 :)